# How to have an opaque background image on a div?

Tags: css, background-image, opacity

I have a `<div>` which contains a bunch of `<p>`s and would like to have an opaque background image behind text, scaled to fill the entire `<div>`. I.e. no matter how much text I add or remove, the image should grow or shrink to cover the entire background of the `<div>`.

And only the image should have opacity. Text within the div should be solid black.

How do I do that, please? (and do I have to worry about browsers which do not support CSS3?)

Comment: guess I'm confused when you mean opaque? are you using an image or a background color/gradiant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answer] from o.p.

I stepped back and looked at the problem another way and found an answer which is cross-browser and does not need CSS3.

I fired up [The Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) and added opactiy into the image itself! Exactly what I sought to do, with no fancy CSS3 necessary ;-)

Thanks very much for your help, @JSW189. I hope you don't mind me posting in your answer, but this is the solution which I chose.

---

You want to use the [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-image) property to add the image, then `background-size:100%` to have the background image fill the entire div.

```
div {
    background-image:url('image_url_goes_here.jpg');
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YJZRE/6/).

Further, if you would like to toggle with the opacity, you can use the [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/opacity) property. It is set to `opacity:1` (opaque) by default, but you can change that by toggling the opacity between `1` and `0`. So, for example, if you want an opacity of 50%, you would use `opacity:.5`.

[Opacity JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YJZRE/7/).

Note that [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size) is a CSS3 property. You can see a [browser compatibility chart here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts). However, this problem can be solved by libraries like [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

Comment: JSW189's answer is correct HOWEVER [`background-size`](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) is a new CSS3 property so you'll need a [polyfill](http://nooshu.com/jquery-plug-in-scalable-background-image) for it to work in older browsers.

Comment: +1 Thanks for such excellent help. However, when I look at yout JFiddle opacity example in FireFox 19, it seems to me that the text is just as opaque as the image (and continues to be when I change the opacity). That is, it seems like `opacity` is being applied to everything inside the div, not just the image (the same thing happens in Chrome)

Comment: @Mawg. That is one of the major setbacks of opacity; all the child elements are affected by the opacity as well. The only way to avoid this issue is to move the child out of the parent.

Comment: The above can be seen in jsfiddle.net/YJZRE/10/    Also, I do not like that you put a height & width on the div - what if the user resizes their browser.  But if we remove those, then only the top of the image is shown - I want it to shrink or grow to fill the div, no matter how much text I add or remove to/from the div. See http://jsfiddle.net/YJZRE/13/

Comment: @Mawg. Take a look at this: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: +1 an dthanks. I hope you don't mind me editing your question to include my own answer, but any future seacrhers will look at teh awarded answer.

Comment: @Mawg: You should post your solution as your own, separate answer and to mark it correct.

Comment: +1 I know that i could, but you put in a lot of work, so I want you to have the points. Anyone searching will find my solutionn.

Comment: @Mawg: If my answer solved your issue, you should "check" it as correct (the green check mark next to the up/down vote). If you did something different, you should post it as your own answer and check that as the correct answer. Others will see my answer regardless, and I will still receive points by users upvoting my answer.